# ng-model-option rollback changes on whole form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

have a quick question.

I have a form with whole bunch of fields that could be updated from UI.

I found a directive called "ng-model-option" that seems to be handling those kind of issues.

My question is: is it possible to rollback changes on whole form without specifying `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit'}"`
on every input fieldin my form?

Or, this directive look on every field and only submit those fields that were modified?

Thank you for your help and explanation in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could have all of your fields bound to a single object, i.e.

```
$scope.model = {
    foo: '',
    bar: '',
    etc: ''        
};
```

That way you could store a copy of the model, and reset the bound model at any point you wish.

For example to undo all of the changes after a failed service call:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    yourService.update(model).then(function(result) {
        // handle the success.
    }, function(err) {
        $scope.model = $scope.originalModel;
    });
}
```

Or maybe reloading the page is an option for you?

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. what if i have a huge data set coming back, storing a copy would make it 2x bigger thats my onnly consern.

Comment: You're only storing it on the client-side though - plus if it's form-type data that the user is modifying how large can it be?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution by using and mapping everything to ng-model-option directive

```
<form name="EditUserForm" class="col-md-12 form-horizontal top-buffer">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>User Id:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.UserID" ng-disabled="true" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Department Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.Department.DepartmentName" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" />-->
                            <select class="form-control info-textbox" ng-options="department.DepartmentName for department in departments"
                                    ng-model="selectedDepartment"
                                    ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode"
                                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.FirstName" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.LastName" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.Email" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Phone:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.Phone" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Login:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.LoginName" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control info-textbox" ng-model="user.Password" ng-readonly="isReadOnlyMode" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Buttons-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary info-button" name="btnEdit" ng-click="flipBetweenEditMode(isReadOnlyMode)" ng-show="isReadOnlyMode">
                                <span>Edit</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary info-button" name="btnEdit" ng-click="flipBetweenEditMode(isReadOnlyMode)" ng-show="!isReadOnlyMode">
                                <span>Cancel</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary info-button" name="btnSave" ng-click="saveChangesToUser(user, isReadOnlyMode)" ng-show="!isReadOnlyMode">
                                <span>Save</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
                            <div back-button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and then controller

```
$scope.flipBetweenEditMode = function (isReadOnlyMode) {
    if (!isReadOnlyMode) {
        $scope.EditUserForm.$rollbackViewValue();
    }
    console.log(isReadOnlyMode);
    $scope.isReadOnlyMode = !isReadOnlyMode;
};
```

on cancel this will roll back all the changes and restore model at its first stage.